# How to declare a variable inside url_for to pass into function being called in flask?

Tags: html, flask, jinja2

Basically I have a list called books, and I displayed a link to each book in the books list and I want that if the user clicks on any of the books it will take them to a display page that displays information about the book. To do this I need to get the name of link that the user is clicking because the will be the name of the book, so I can pass it into my function to get info. This is my code using Jinja2.

```html
{% for book in loopthis %}
<a href="{{ url_for('displayinfo')}}">{{ book }}</a>
{%endfor%}
```

I dont know how to declare a variable equal to the book name. I was thinking of doing something like this, but it's not working.

```html
{% for book in loopthis %}
<a href="{{ url_for('displayinfo', name={{ book }})}}">{{ book }}</a>
{%endfor%}
```

this is my flask code.

```html
@app.route("/displayinfo", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def displayinfo():

    name = request.args.get('name', type=str)
    findauthor = db.execute("SELECT author FROM books WHERE     title=:title", {"title": name}).fetchone()
    findtitle = db.execute("SELECT title FROM books WHERE title=:title", {"title": name}).fetchone()
    findyear = db.execute("SELECT year FROM books WHERE title=:title", {"title": name}).fetchone()
    findisbn = db.execute("SELECT isbn FROM books WHERE title=:title", {"title": name}).fetchone()
    
    return render_template("displayinfo.html", printauthor = findauthor, printtitle = findtitle, printyear = findyear, printisbn = findisbn)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should send something like id of your book to this function or its name and in function search for this book in your database.

```py
{% for book in loopthis %}
<a href="{{ url_for('displayinfo', name=book.id)}}">{{ book }}</a>
{%endfor%}
```

or

```py
{% for book in loopthis %}
<a href="{{ url_for('displayinfo', name=book.name)}}">{{ book }}</a>
{%endfor%}
```

And the function must look like this:

```py
@route('/smth/<id:int>')
def displayinfo(id):
    book = findBookById(id)
```

Comment: Thank you! How does it know to get the name from the database if you say book.name? do I have to create a function or something?

Comment: You should store all books in database and create request to filter book with the same name.